# Unable to connect to database using homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm using homestead globally and I'm getting this error when I'm trying to add my database details to datagrip

> The specified database user/password combination is rejected: [28000] FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.10.1", user "homestead", database "dogs", SSL on

this is my Homestead.yaml file

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/projects/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: site1.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/site1/public
    - map: site2.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/site2/public
    - map: site3.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/site3/public
      php: "7.4"
    - map: dogs.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/dogs/public
      php: "7.4"


databases:
    - site1
    - site2
    - site3
    - dogs

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: true
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

#services:
#    - enabled:
#        - "postgresql@12-main"
#    - disabled:
#        - "postgresql@11-main"

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

and what I have in my datagrip when I try to connect

```
Host: 192.168.10.10
Port: 5432
Authentication: User & Password
User: homestead
Password: secret
Database: dogs
```

Comment: Why not using the default forwarded ports? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#ports Try connecting to localhost:33060 it should tunnel to the virtual machine's mysql instance

Comment: why your error is about host 192.168.10.1 while you are connecting 192.168.10.10 ?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem once. I was working with grafana local at the time. Some setups which use postgresql cannot work properly localy with the 10.10 adress.

My fix was changing the ip of my vagrant box to 10.11 .
this fixed the issue.

And if you want to revert that for other project's you can easily do:

```
#ip: "192.168.10.11"
ip: "192.168.10.10"
```

Not sure if this will be the solution for your problem. But worth a try